# How far back can AirWatch retrieve browsing history?

Tags: privacy, iphone

My employer is installing airwatch on company iPhones, I assume they will be able to monitor web activity but will they be able to go back and see web activity prior to the installation of airwatch?

All of the searches would have been done off of the company wifi.

Comment: this is a question for AirWatch support or your IT dept